# How many processors are on the server?

Tags: central-processing-unit

On a server which has two sockets for CPUs, I'm going to determine whether I‌ can add a new CPU to enhance the computation power. I‌ don't have physical access to the server.

```
# nproc --all
32

# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 45
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               2499.765
CPU max MHz:           2800.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
BogoMIPS:              4001.49
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7,16-23
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15,24-31
```

On the I[ntel page](http://ark.intel.com/products/64590/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2650-20M-Cache-2_00-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI) on  E5-2650 I see

```
# of Cores 8
# of Threads 16
```

So, I'm confused and wondering whether I‌ can add a second CPU to this server, or it already has 2 CPUs?

Comment: To make lscpu easier to read and easier to sort and deduce sockets, `lscpu --parse=SOCKET,CPU`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sockets are already occupied.

```
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
```

Also, `nproc` lists 32 cores. Since the [E5-2650](https://ark.intel.com/de/products/64590/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2650-20M-Cache-2_00-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI) has 8 cores and 2 threads per core, this means that you need to have 2 physical processors to get to 32 threads.